# impute duplicate record id from conditions on other columns sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates, subquery, imputation

Imagine I have this data set:

```
serial_id | name | address_id | id_duplicates | dob
_______________________________________________________
1         | JOHN | QWERTY     | NULL          | 10/2001
2         | JOHN | QWERTY     | NULL          | 10/2001
3         | JOHN | AZERTY     | NULL          | 10/2001
4         | JOHN | QWERTY     | NULL          | 09/2001
5         | MARY | QWERTY     | NULL          | 10/2001
6         | MARY | AZERTY     | NULL          | 10/2001
7         | MARY | AZERTY     | NULL          | 10/2001
```

I want to fill `id_duplicates` with *any* of the `serial_id` when records match on some conditions.

If I want records with same match `name`, `address_id` and `dob` to share a single id from the `serial_id` column, I would then for example have:

```
serial_id | name | address_id | id_duplicates | dob
_______________________________________________________
1         | JOHN | QWERTY     | 1             | 10/2001  --> match
2         | JOHN | QWERTY     | 1             | 10/2001  --> match
3         | JOHN | AZERTY     | 3             | 10/2001  --> no match on address_id
4         | JOHN | QWERTY     | 4             | 09/2001  --> no match on dob
5         | MARY | QWERTY     | 5             | 10/2001  --> no match on name
6         | MARY | AZERTY     | 6             | 10/2001  --> match 
7         | MARY | AZERTY     | 6             | 10/2001  --> match
```

I've been miserably trying to do this with nested queries which I am ebarassed to post as they make no sense...

any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dense_rank()`:

```
select t.*,
       dense_rank() over (order by name, address, dob) as id_duplicate
from t;
```

If you want this in an `update`, here is one method:

```
update t
    set id_duplicate = tt.new_id_duplicate
    from (select t.*, 
                 dense_rank() over (order by name, address, dob) as new_id_duplicate
          from t
         ) tt
    where tt.serial_id = t.serial_id;
```

Comment: I get `Query Error: error: column reference "id_duplicate" is ambiguous`. Here's the [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2MKDdqnMh6XWcybNHux7a8/0#&togetherjs=n79PNzakG6)

Comment: It worked - I simply renamed the `as id_duplicate` to something else. THANK YOU SO MUCH.